# get text value from selected radiobutton with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of a selected radio button with jQuery. I generate my html-elements with jquery from a json-template, this is my code for generating radio buttons:

```
function AddRadio(labelName, buttons, i, paneIndex, dataID) {
        $('#Ctabs1-pane' + paneIndex + '').append('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label">' + labelName + '</label><div class="col-lg-10"  id="' + dataID + '"></div></div>');
        $.each(buttons, function (j, value) {
            $('#' + dataID).append('<div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="' + value + '">' + value + '</label></div>');
        });
    }
```

i try to get the selected radiobutton with this code:

```
return $("input[type='radio'].radioBtnClass:checked").val();
```

But this gives me `undefined`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `.radioBtnClass` in `AddRadio`

Comment: i thought that was added when clicked?

Comment: `$("input[type='radio'][name='optionsRadios']:checked").val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector match input element with class `radioBtnClass` but you're not added it when append. Either add that class into your input:

```
$('#' + dataID).append('<div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="optionsRadios" value="' + value + '">' + value + '</label></div>');
```

or target it by name instead:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='optionsRadios']:checked").val();
```